# Data insertion in database using jpa issueing error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am new to the JPA world. Here I have tried to make a simple POS. The problem is that when there is no predefined value in tables although the PK is auto-incremented, data is not being inserted into DB. But if I set a predefined row into the tables then there are no issues and data is being inserted successfully. please help me.

The following are my Java classes, and I am using Mysql for DB.

```
@Entity  
@Table(name = "card_payment")
public class Card_payment {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
int id;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
private Orders order;

@Column(name = "issuing_bank")
String issuing_bank;

@Column(name = "card_type")
String card_type;

@Column(name = "card_expiry_date")
String card_expiry_date;

@Column(name = "amount")
int amount;


public Card_payment() {
    super();
}
public Orders getOrder() {
    return order;
}
public void setOrder(Orders order) {
    this.order = order;
}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getIssuing_bank() {
    return issuing_bank;
}
public void setIssuing_bank(String issuing_bank) {
    this.issuing_bank = issuing_bank;
}
public String getCard_type() {
    return card_type;
}
public void setCard_type(String card_type) {
    this.card_type = card_type;
}
public String getCard_expiry_date() {
    return card_expiry_date;
}
public void setCard_expiry_date(String card_expiry_date) {
    this.card_expiry_date = card_expiry_date;
}
public int getAmount() {
    return amount;
}
public void setAmount(int amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
}

}




@Entity  
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
int id;

@Column(name = "name")
String name;

@Column(name = "mobile_no")
long mobile_no;

@Column(name = "address")
String address;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        fetch=FetchType.LAZY)  
private List<Orders> orders;;



public Customer() {
    super();
}

public List<Orders> getOrders() {
    return orders;
}
public void setOrders(List<Orders> orders) {
    this.orders = orders;
}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public long getMobile_no() {
    return mobile_no;
}
public void setMobile_no(long mobile_no) {
    this.mobile_no = mobile_no;
}
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}


}



@Entity  
@Table(name = "Item")
public class Item {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
int id;

@Column(name = "name")
String name;

@Column(name = "unit")
String unit;

@Column(name = "stock_quantity")
int stock_quantity;

@Column(name = "reorder_level")
int reorder_level;

@Column(name = "unit_price")
int unit_price;

@Column(name = "tax_percentage")
float tax_percentage;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "item", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        fetch=FetchType.LAZY)  
private List<Orderline> orderLines;


public Item() {
    super();
}

public List<Orderline> getOrderLines() {
    return orderLines;
}

public void setOrderLines(List<Orderline> orderLines) {
    this.orderLines = orderLines;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getUnit() {
    return unit;
}
public void setUnit(String unit) {
    this.unit = unit;
}
public int getStock_quantity() {
    return stock_quantity;
}
public void setStock_quantity(int stock_quantity) {
    this.stock_quantity = stock_quantity;
}
public int getReorder_level() {
    return reorder_level;
}
public void setReorder_level(int reorder_level) {
    this.reorder_level = reorder_level;
}
public int getUnit_price() {
    return unit_price;
}
public void setUnit_price(int unit_price) {
    this.unit_price = unit_price;
}
public float getTax_percentage() {
    return tax_percentage;
}
public void setTax_percentage(float tax_percentage) {
    this.tax_percentage = tax_percentage;
}



}




@Entity  
@Table(name = "OrderLine")
public class Orderline {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
int id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "itemId")
private Item item;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "orderId")
private Orders orders;

@Column(name = "unit_cost")
float unit_cost;

@Column(name = "unit")
int unit;

@Column(name = "tax_percentage")
float tax_percentage;

@Column(name = "quantity")
int quantity;

@Column(name = "amount")
int amount;

@Column(name = "tax_amount")
float tax_amount;

@Column(name = "line_total")
int line_total;


public Orderline() {
    super();
}


public Item getItem() {
    return item;
}


public void setItem(Item item) {
    this.item = item;
}


public Orders getOrders() {
    return orders;
}
public void setOrders(Orders orders) {
    this.orders = orders;
}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}


public float getUnit_cost() {
    return unit_cost;
}
public void setUnit_cost(float unit_cost) {
    this.unit_cost = unit_cost;
}
public int getUnit() {
    return unit;
}
public void setUnit(int unit) {
    this.unit = unit;
}
public float getTax_percentage() {
    return tax_percentage;
}
public void setTax_percentage(float tax_percentage) {
    this.tax_percentage = tax_percentage;
}
public int getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}
public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}
public int getAmount() {
    return amount;
}
public void setAmount(int amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
}
public float getTax_amount() {
    return tax_amount;
}
public void setTax_amount(float tax_amount) {
    this.tax_amount = tax_amount;
}
public int getLine_total() {
    return line_total;
}
public void setLine_total(int line_total) {
    this.line_total = line_total;
}




    @Entity  
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Orders {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
int id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "customerId")
private Customer customer;

@Column(name = "order_date")
String order_date;

@Column(name = "delivery_address")
String delivery_address;

@Column(name = "total")
long total;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "orders", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        fetch=FetchType.LAZY)  
private List<Orderline> orderlines;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "order")
private Cash_payment cash_payment;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "order")
private Card_payment card_payment;


@OneToOne(mappedBy = "order")
private Cheque_payment cheque_payment;


public Orders() {
    super();
}


public Cash_payment getCash_payment() {
    return cash_payment;
}


public void setCash_payment(Cash_payment cash_payment) {
    this.cash_payment = cash_payment;
}


public Card_payment getCard_payment() {
    return card_payment;
}


public void setCard_payment(Card_payment card_payment) {
    this.card_payment = card_payment;
}


public Cheque_payment getCheque_payment() {
    return cheque_payment;
}


public void setCheque_payment(Cheque_payment cheque_payment) {
    this.cheque_payment = cheque_payment;
}


public List<Orderline> getOrderlines() {
    return orderlines;
}


public void setOrderlines(List<Orderline> orderlines) {
    this.orderlines = orderlines;
}


public Customer getCustomer() {
    return customer;
}
public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
    this.customer = customer;
}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getOrder_date() {
    return order_date;
}
public void setOrder_date(String order_date) {
    this.order_date = order_date;
}

public String getDelivery_address() {
    return delivery_address;
}
public void setDelivery_address(String delivery_address) {
    this.delivery_address = delivery_address;
}
public long getTotal() {
    return total;
}
public void setTotal(long total) {
    this.total = total;
}


}

public class JPAExample {

private static EntityManager entityManager = EntityManagerUtil.getEntityManager();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JPAExample example = new JPAExample();

    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

    Orders order = new Orders();
    order.setOrder_date("2019/05/05");
    order.setTotal(1000);
    order.setDelivery_address("kolkata");

    Item item = new Item();
    item.setName("cream");
    item.setReorder_level(10);
    item.setUnit_price(10);
    item.setUnit("kg");
    item.setTax_percentage((float) 12.5);
    item.setStock_quantity(20);
    item.setReorder_level(5);


    Orderline orderline = new Orderline();
    orderline.setAmount(1);
    orderline.setItem(item);
    orderline.setLine_total(200);
    orderline.setQuantity(1);

    List<Orderline> orderlns = new ArrayList<>();
    orderlns.add(orderline);
    item.setOrderLines(orderlns);


    Customer customer = new Customer();
    customer.setId(1234);
    customer.setName("Tanusha");
    customer.setMobile_no(Long.valueOf("9609"));
    customer.setAddress("u-86, garia");

    orderline.setOrders(order);

    List<Orderline> orderLinesList = new ArrayList<>();
    orderLinesList.add(orderline);
    order.setOrderlines(orderLinesList);


    order.setCustomer(customer);

    List<Orders> orderList = new ArrayList<>();
    orderList.add(order);
    customer.setOrders(orderList);


    Card_payment cp = new Card_payment();
    cp.setAmount(200);
    cp.setCard_expiry_date("2019/05/05");
    cp.setCard_type("visa");
    cp.setIssuing_bank("SBI");

    cp.setOrder(order);

    order.setCard_payment(cp);


    entityManager.merge(order);

    try {
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
    }
}


}
```

Comment: What is the error which you get? BTW: you should move the entityManager.merge line into the try..catch block.

Comment: "com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails"- something like that. and it was happening between order and card_payment table.

Comment: Please paste the exact error message into your question. "between order and card_payment table": I think you understood something wrong. Until the line "entityManager.merge" you only deal with java classes, not with tables. SQL comes into play when asking entityManager to save the entity (and its dependencies) into DB. Obviously you didn't setup your entity instances.

Comment: sorry my mistake this was an exeption not an error.

Comment: now, what is happening if I insert any row in all the tables at the time of their creation, there is no issue, data is being inserted finely later on.